# Sort a list using parallel sorting and multiple fields

Tags: multithreading, sorting, parallel-processing, java-8, comparator

I have a list of object and i am sorting this list based on two parameters:
1. First Name, and
2. Last Name.

So the requirement is like, first sort the list on the basis of first name and sort on the basis of last name.

I have implemented this using the Comparator.compairing and thenCompairing methods as follows:

```
Comparator<Employee> groupComparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
                                                .thenComparing(Employee::getLastName);
```

and, it is working very fine.

Now what i want is to use the concept of parallel processing/sorting for sorting in parallel using the multiple threads or in multi-threaded environment. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight modification, but this should work as well:

```
List<Employee> sortedEmployees = employees.parallelStream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
                     .thenComparing(Employee::getLastName))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You see - that is one of the beauties about streams - turning a solution into parallel might be as simple as turning `stream()` into `parallelStream()`!

But as usual when using **parallelStream**:

- measure its effects
- be prepared for surprises and the need for fine tuning

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using the Arrays.parallelSort method as follows:

```
List<Employee> emps  = getEmployees();
Comparator<Employee> groupComparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
                                                    .thenComparing(Employee::getLastName);
Employee[] empArr = employees.toArray(new Employee[emps.size()]);

//Parallel sorting
Arrays.parallelSort(empArr, groupComparator);
```

It has been added java 8 and according to the documentations:

> The sorting algorithm is a parallel sort-merge that breaks the array into sub-arrays that are themselves sorted and then merged. When the sub-array length reaches a minimum granularity, the sub-array is sorted using the appropriate Arrays.sort method. If the length of the specified array is less than the minimum granularity, then it is sorted using the appropriate Arrays.sort method. The algorithm requires a working space no greater than the size of the original array. The ForkJoin common pool is used to execute any parallel tasks.

It will solve my issue here

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `streams` as well. By using `streams` we don't need to copy the `List` to an array before sorting.

```
Stream<Employee> sorted = employees.stream()
                                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName)
                                   .thenComparing(Employee::getLastName))   
                                   .parallel();   

sorted.forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This will sort the data, then, `forEach` will print the elements in an arbitrary order…

Comment: So, the correct approach is to collect to a List ? Does that print in the sorted order ?

Comment: Compare the contracts of [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [`forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-)… Of course, collecting into a list will produce a list in the right order, but this isn’t necessary, when you only want to print the elements.